# how to get public IP of instance using cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-cloudformation

I want to output public IP of my instance in cloud formation. This is the relevant part of my yaml file.

What attribute do I have to specify to get public IP. (Here myec2 is where I described my instance)

```
 <code>
 .
 .
 Outputs:
  instancedetails:
    Description: ec2 details
    Value: !GetAtt Myec2.instance
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are all the possible return values: **[AWS::EC2::Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#aws-properties-ec2-instance-returnvalues)**

I.e. in your case it will be `!GetAtt Myec2.PublicIp`

Unless of course you create *ElasticIP* in the stack in which case it would be `!Ref MyEip` (see [Return Values section for **AWS::EC2::EIP**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html#aws-resource-ec2-eip-ref)).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: thax for the help...its working now